# Div not being Responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a website [HERE](http://mediamantra.co/xpose) and it is responsive, however there's a `<div id="videoswrap">` that os not responsive. 
When I give `Height : 150px;`, it gives desired result on PC Screen, and breaks as soon as I re-size the window for a smaller view (obviously due to fixed height).

This is my website on Fullscreen : 
[image]

and this is how it looks on Smaller View : 
[image]

As you can see the VIDEOS THUMBNAILS are coming out of the DIV, I want the div to increase its height accordingly so that all the Video thumbnails accommodate in that.

Comment: That works but vacant spaces are left behind when you resize. To remove vacant spaces you need to target different screen resolutions using media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height` from `#videoswrap` and `float` from `#videos li`:

Then apply:

```
#videos li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a Genius. I applied it exactly and it worked. Thanks a Ton. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `display: inline-block` to the `#videos li` and to the div with white border.